# MVC3 HttpStatusCodeResult Not working in OnActionExecuted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which uses the new MVC3 HttpStatusCodeResult:

```
  protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(304, "Not Modified");
  }
```

I am still getting a 200OK and I can't figure out why. Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works for me:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(304, "Not Modified");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the result is what we would expect:

[image]